# Substrate Node Template Build Error, syn::group private

Tags: build

[image]

while building substrate node template
versions: polkadot-v0.9.19, polkadot-v0.9.27
get the below error
rustup version

```
nightly-2022-02-15-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.60.0-nightly (c5c610aad 2022-02-14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply do this (you don't have to modify the lock file manually):

```
cargo update -p syn --precise 1.0.96
```

---

If you have the plan to update your Substrate version.

Update the Substrate to this [commit](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11707), which could fix this problem permanently.

Comment: `error: failed to select a version for the requirement `syn = "^1.0.98"``

Comment: looks like we need version above or equal to syn = "^1.0.98"; which has the same error message of being private

Comment: You need to downgrade other dep first. I guess it is `cargo update -p ctor --precise 0.1.22`.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade your current `syn` version `1.0.99` into `1.0.96` in my case

Step:

- Go to `Cargo.lock`
- Search `name = "syn"`  in `Cargo.lock`
- Delete `checksum` line of `syn`
- Replace `1.0.99` by `1.0.96`
- `cargo build --release` again

Comment: Isn't Cargo.lock autogenerated and it gets rewritten?

Comment: yeah. you should use `cargo update -p syn --precise 1.0.96` instead of my solution