# How to fix "module group is private" error when using frame-support-procedural-tools v3.0.0?

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template, rust, orml

I'm trying to use orml-tokens in my Substrate project and encountered the following error:

```
    error[E0603]: module `group` is private
     --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/frame-support-procedural-tools-3.0.0/src/syn_ext.rs:47:53
      |
  47  |                 let syn::group::$name { token, content } = syn::group::$parse(input)?;
      |                                                                 ^^^^^ private module
      |
  note: the module `group` is defined here
     --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/syn-1.0.109/src/lib.rs:308:1
      |
  308 | mod group;
      | ^^^^^^^^^

error[E0603]: module `group` is private
     --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/frame-support-procedural-tools-3.0.0/src/syn_ext.rs:47:14
      |
  47  |                 let syn::group::$name { token, content } = syn::group::$parse(input)?;
      |                          ^^^^^ private module
      |
  note: the module `group` is defined here
     --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/syn-1.0.109/src/lib.rs:308:1
      |
  308 | mod group;
      | ^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm using frame-support-procedural-tools v3.0.0 How can I resolve this issue? Are there any workarounds or specific dependency versions I should use to avoid this error?

**Using rustc version: rustc 1.68.0-nightly (574b64a97 2022-12-31)**

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with mistmached versions, what version of Susbtrate are you using in your project?

You can try to update Substrate if you are using an old version, and have  the frame-support-procedural-tools v3.0.0 to the last one: [see Cargo.toml](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/support/procedural/Cargo.toml).

Or update the library is failling manually with:

```
cargo update -p syn
```

See this old question on StackExchange: [Substrate Node Template Build Error, syn::group private](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4305/substrate-node-template-build-error-syngroup-private)

Comment: I tried this way but still i have error

Comment: I want to use Multicurrncy and i import `orlm` in the project . After that i faced this issue

Comment: it show me this error : `There are multiple `syn` packages in your project, and the specification `syn` is ambiguous.
Please re-run this command with `-p <spec>` where `<spec>` is one of the following:
  syn@1.0.109
  syn@2.0.13
`